# Scikit-learn throwing warning for increased # of iterations for Lasso

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am trying to run `Linear Regression` with `LASSO` using Python's `Scikit-learn` package.

For Lasso, my configurations are as follows:

```
lasso_eps = 0.0001
lasso_alpha = 20
lasso_iter = 5000
```

And the code for the model is as follows:

```
lasso_cv = LassoCV(eps=lasso_eps, n_alphas=lasso_alpha, max_iter=lasso_iter, normalize=True, cv=5)
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, interaction_only=False), lasso_cv)
model.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())

y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
model_score = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Accuracy: {model_score}")
```

Though, I am getting my model score properly; I am getting the following warning as well:

```
/Users/pankajkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py:491: ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations. Fitting data with very small alpha may cause precision problems.
  ConvergenceWarning)
```

Could anyone suggest, what this warning means and how it can be resolved?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Adding the following `ignore_warnings` helped in removing the warning:

`with ignore_warnings(category=ConvergenceWarning):`

But still, I am curious, what this meant.